# Installed Windows8 and now my grub is gone, help?

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

So I installed windows 8 on a newly created partition on disk0.  Before this I had a dual boot with Windows 7, and Ubuntu 12.04.  After the installation of Win8, i no longer see the boot loader, grub appear. I get the normal windows boot option which only gives me the following, win7, and win8...  uughh !!  I tried re-installing Ubuntu but still nothing.

Is there anyway to get ubuntu back on my machine without destroying my windows installation, or Win8 for that matter.
Also note, windows doesn't recognize my other disk as I left disk1 completely for ubuntu.  The only time I can see this is in disk manager obviously within windows.  When I load Ubuntu from a liveCD, I can see it...

very annoying, starting to hate windows8..

Comment: Since it sounds like Windows 8 didn't overwrite Ubuntu, but just the boot loader (as all Windows versions do when they're installed), you can solve this problem [the same way as it's solved for other Windows OSes, by reinstalling GRUB to the MBR](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). (We'll probably close this as a duplicate of that question.)

Comment: i am not quite sure but windows8 use secure boot to prevent dual boot with linux. see this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/06/canonical-clarify-ubuntu-secureboot-plans